# Looking for a position "with a stable company" or "in a stable company"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I would like to know which of the following is correct:

> - I am looking for a position of Senior Developer **with a stable company**.
> - I am looking for a position of Senior Developer **in a stable company**.

For instance, in the article ["Job Interview Question: Why Are You Leaving Your Job?"](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/interviewquestionsanswers/a/interviewleave.htm), the author — who is, as far as I understand, a native English speaker —, gives the following example:

> I am seeking a position **with a stable company** with room for growth and opportunity for advancement.

Here is another example at the website of the company [Pacific Drilling](http://www.pacificdrilling.com/careers/application-faq/default.aspx#_ctrl0_ctl48_rtrQuestion_ctl00_hrefQuestion) (quote):

> How do I apply for a position **with** Pacific Drilling?

I just want to make sure, is the use of "with a company" the correct form for my example sentence?  Or maybe such usage is common in the US?

Would be highly interested to hear the opinion of native English speakers.

---

**Edit:** I emphasize, what is the correct/common form with respect to my *particular* sentence: "with" or "in"?

Of course, I know there are cases when you can use one or another.

Comment: Notice that your native speakers say *a* position, but you say *the* position:  Meaning that there is only one position at that company, and you are looking for it.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, thank you for pointing it out. I thought that, in this case, it meant more like a **concrete** position, not the only one... btw why "your native speakers"? My native language is Russian.

Comment: By "your native speakers" I intended "the native speakers you quoted in the question".

Comment: @GEdgar I see. I visited Your account page and You happened to be an American Math professor. Could You say, is using "with" in my specific sentence above the correct/common form? I mean would it be OK for an American to use "with" in the above mentioned sentence? **You** should be a native English speaker.

Comment: Both *in* and *with* seem grammatical to me.

Comment: With regard to your question "Why -1?": You did nothing wrong, I suspect that someone on this site felt that your question didn't raise a sufficiently meaningful question of English language and usage—but instead amounted to a request for editing help—and expressed that opinion by downvoting your question. Unfortunately, many downvoters don't explain their action, which leaves the downvoted person as much in the dark as if they hadn't voted at all. I would have thought that asking whether "with" or "in" was a better preposition choice in this instance was a valid (albeit specific) question.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thank you, your explanation makes sense. It's just my native language is Russian, so I wanted to clarify some moments in English and I thought that this is the right place. I am an active Stack Overflow user. Over there the community is the largest, people usually are more active and specific about their behavior. But what to do, it's OK with me ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a native speaker, but I believe that both *I am seeking a position* and *I am looking for a position* are correct, and I would definitely say and write *with a company*.

If you are not applying for an advertised position, you may write

> I am looking for a position of Senior Developer.

or

> I am looking for a Senior Developer position.

If you are applying for an advertised position then you would simply write

> I am applying for the position of Senior Developer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not the advertised position. I am purely interested in what is the correct form: using "**with**" or "**in**" in my concrete sentence. I know there are cases when you can use "in" or "with". But just in my concrete example, which is the correct / common usage. Anyways, thanks for sharing your opinion. +1

Comment: The correct form is *to look for a position with a company* or *to seek a position with a company*. Also, I answered the way I did because you had written *looking for the position* instead of *looking for a position*.

Comment: I see. Thanks, +1. Just waiting, maybe some Americans or Brits will also give their 2 cents

Comment: My 2 cents: I think lots of people use *in a company* — I wouldn't call it wrong — but to me *with a company* sounds more formal, which as a job applicant is definitely something you want to aim for.

Comment: @PeterShor Wow, another American Math Professor, and now from MIT! Thank You, sir, that's what I thought - using "with" is more formal/official, and this is exactly what I need. I'm glad my suggestion was confirmed. I really appreciate Your help.